# How to encapsulate an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to write a getter for an ArrayList in Java such that the list returned cannot be modified (ideally at compile time). I know there must be some simple way to do this but it is eluding me. Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: (The language is called Java, not JAVA. It's not an acronym. Edited accordingly.)

Comment: There is no way in Java to prevent modification attempts at compile time. The only choice is to follow the given answers, which prevent modification at runtime by throwing exceptions in modificator methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Collections.unmodifiableList(...)` is simple solution. Better one would be to use `ImmutableList` from google-guava library

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Collections.unmodifiableList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29). As short example is available [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/TocreateareadonlylistusetheunmodifiableListmethodoftheCollectionsclass.htm).